# BruTile Getting Started

Tags: gis, tiles, tms, sharpmap

Is there any documentation on how to get started with BruTile please?

I am currently working with SharpMap and I need to pre cache tiles to speed up the process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking into this today :) 
The Mapsui project [site](https://github.com/mapsui/mapsui/) heavily relies on SharpMap and BruTile. The project site contains excellent samples to get you started. I also suggest you have a look at the [architecture](http://mapsui.github.io/Mapsui/documentation/Async-Fetching.html) description, it might help to know what are you going to deal with before digging deep into the samples.

Answer (score 1):

It is this simple to use BruTile with mapsui in a WPF application:

```
using BruTile.Predefined;
using Mapsui.Desktop;
using Mapsui.Layers;


//myMapControl is Mapsui.UI.Wpf.MapControl
this.myMapControl.RenderMode = Mapsui.UI.Wpf.RenderMode.Wpf;
this.myMapControl.Map = new Mapsui.Map();
this.myMapControl.Map.Layers.Add(new TileLayer(KnownTileSources.Create()));
```

[image]